# Fix pavucontrol Alsa mixer with creative card

Tags: 10.10, sound, pulseaudio, soundcard, speakers

I have been desperately trying to get my creative x-fi soundcard to work with my 10.10 install and I am almost there!  I have 1 speaker working and when I open volume control I see that my device is Creative X-Fi (Also mixer).

However, it appears to be stuck on mono.  When I open `pavucontrol` I get a message that says `Connection failed: Connection refused` and it exits.  Before it closes I can see that playback is set to mono but it won't let me change before it closes.

Can someone help me over this last hump?  I am running 32 bit 10.10 any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this tutorial :
[HOWTO: PulseAudio Fixes & System-Wide Equalizer Support](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=789578)

Do only **Part A**.

This should fix the `Connection failed: Connection refused` problem.

For the mono sound output (if the problem is still not fixed) I need more info on the audio card, there is a lot of Creative X-fi cards.

But first you can try to open pavucontrol and go to the Configuration tab and try differents profiles and see if one work better than the others.

I also found a bug that seem related ([[SB-XFi - Creative X-Fi] digital output only in mono](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/630319)) but it should be fixed already, so try to activate the backports repositery : open Synaptic, go to Settings->Repositeries and to the Update tab and then check "Unsupported updates", close the window, reload in Synaptic and then update all your packages.

Comment: thanks for the response, unfortunately this hasn't resolved my issue.  trying to open pulseaudio first with `pulseaudio & pavucontrol` still results in the same error.  As far as my card  AlsaMixer says the chip is 20k1, it is the Fatal1ty branded card.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I just did a new fresh install to help my way around this problem.  Hopefully I won't break it again getting my soundcard working.  Now I have 4 speakers working.. just need center and sub >.<